# How to create Django_filter in Checkbox view on my website front panel?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter, django-filters

I am using `django_fiter` package for filter data, but it's displaying filter in the `input box` or some filter in the `dropdowns`, but I want all filters in the checkbox (like as Django default admin panel filter), please let me know how I can convert it in checkbox filter on my website front panel.

Here is my code for filter view form...

```
 <form method="get">
     {{ filter.form|bootstrap }}
     <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

and here is my `views.py` file code...

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['saleprice', 'title','veg_non','brand','supplement']
```

it's looking like this...

[image]

and I want in this format, please let me know how I can customize it.

[image]